# Quotation marks around the title except from books

Tags: biblatex

I need to put German quotation marks (,,text") around all titles in `biblatex` except with titles from books.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{darwin,
    Author = {Charles Darwin},
    Publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
    Title = {The Correspondence of Charles Darwin, 1821-1836},
    Year = {1985}}

@Electronic{wade,
  title     = {Darwin, Ahead of His Time, Is Still Influential},
  author    = {Nicholas Wade},
  date       = {2009-02-09}
  url       = {https://www.nytimes.com/2009/02/10/science/10evolution.html?ref=sciencespecial2},
  urldate   = {2018-10-08}
  }


\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla \autocite{darwin} \autocite{wade}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I only found questions about quotation marks within the title. However, I need quotation marks outside the title. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Traditionally works that stand on their own (books, journal names, ...) are printed in italics, while works that are part of a larger 'container' (chapters in books: `@inbook`, `@incollection`, `@article`s, ...) have their titles in quotation marks. Do you explicitly want all titles in quotation marks?

Comment: Now that I edited the question I'm a bit confused: Do you want the quotation marks to end *before* the "1821-1836"? Would that not mean you actually want quotation marks *within* the title (since the entire title as given in the `.bib` file is "The Correspondence of Charles Darwin, 1821-1836") and not *outside* it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry I drew the quotation marks wrongly. And thanks to your first comment I also noticed that I need all bibliography genres in quotation marks except for titles from books. I'm sorry that I didn't notice that earlier. I added that to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained in the comments, there is some method in the way `biblatex` formats the `title`s for certain entry types: The titles of works that stand on their own (`@book`s, `@collection`s, entire journals, ...; basically anything you can read on the spine or the cover of a book when you stroll through a library) are in italics, while dependent works that constitute only a part of a whole (`@inbook`, `@incollection`, `@article`, ...; these are mainly titles you can only find out about when you open a book or volume and consult the table of contents) have their titles formatted with quotation marks.

You can find an explanation of the default settings in [Remove Quotation Marks from Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864). You probably like to try

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
```

if you really want *only* book titles in italics and the rest in quotation marks, you could try

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot}}
```

For German-style quotation marks it should be enough to load `babel` and pass `ngerman` as loading option and then load `csquotes` for language-dependent quotation marks. Of course that is assuming that the rest of your document is in German, but I think that is a fair assumption if you are looking for German quotation marks.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{darwin,
  author    = {Charles Darwin},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  title     = {The Correspondence of Charles Darwin, 1821--1836},
  year      = {1985},
}
@electronic{wade,
  title   = {Darwin, Ahead of His Time, Is Still Influential},
  author  = {Nicholas Wade},
  date    = {2009-02-09},
  url     = {https://www.nytimes.com/2009/02/10/science/10evolution.html},
  urldate = {2018-10-08},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{darwin} ipsum \autocite{wade}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Darwin, Charles. The Correspondence of Charles Darwin, 1821–1836. Cambridge University Press, 1985.//Wade, Nicholas. „Darwin, Ahead of His Time, Is Still Influential“. 9. Feb. 2009. url: https://www.nytimes.com/2009/02/10/science/10evolution.html (besucht am 08.10.2018).]