# Printing Titles in Bibliography is different for @techreport and @article

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

Why would two bibliography entries display their title in different formats?
For no apparent reason I get one title in double quotes and one title in italics .

[image]

This is in a `\documentclass{book}` I have a `.bib` collection with `@techreport` and `@article` entries.

Compiling with current versions LaTeX, LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX `biblatex` and `biber` or `BibTeX`, so overall, I assume I overlook a fundamental difference in how these to reference classes are handled. Could someone point me to the right region?

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464279/35864 and the links in the answer there.

Comment: Note that the **bold** bibstrings (like "and" and "october") suggest that your document language is not supported by `biblatex`. You may want to look into making `biblatex` support your language (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200932/35864) or switching the bibliography to a supported language.

Comment: That's, right. I simply did not have any language set but used `\babel` and `\csquotes`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments by @moewe, the bold strings in the bibliography indicate a missing or unsupported language.
In my case the language was `nil` as I did not set any but still used the `babel` and the `csquotes` package.
Setting a language resolved my issue.

Comment: The language settings (or their absence) should not have an effect on whether or not titles are formatted in italics or quotation marks. So while the language issues is very relevant, it is not directly related to the question apparently asked in the title of the question or the question body. Maybe you want to edit your question (or your answer) so that answer and question match. This makes this Q&A much more relevant for future visitors of the site.