# Format an @article's title

Tags: biblatex

TL;DR: How do I `DeclareFieldFormat` on an @article's title?

Having a `.bib` entry like this

```
@article{x,
    title={Article Title},
    author={Author},
    journal={Journal Name},
    year={2019}
}
```

And using `[style=alphabetic,sorting=nyt,backend=biber,maxbibnames=999,useprefix=true]{biblatex}`, the bibliography entry gets

> [Aut19] Author. “Article Title”. In: *Journal Name* (2019).

However, I would like to make the Article Title italics instead of in quotes:

> [Aut19] Author. *Article Title*. In: Journal Name (2019).

I tried `\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\emph{#1}}`, which works fine with (for example) @misc, but not with an @article. How do I do that?

Comment: `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\emph{#1}}`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864. `biblatex` allows you to specify type-specific field formats. `\DeclareFieldFormat{title}` redefines the *generic* format that is used if there are no type-specific definitions. `@article`s have a type-specific default and that has to be overwritten with a type-specific declaration: `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}`. If you want to overwrite *all* declarations at once, use the starred form `\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}`

Comment: I knew it must be easy ;) Thanks. Would you post this as a reply so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [Remove Quotation Marks from Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864) `biblatex`'s field formats allow for generic and type-specific formatting. `@article`s have a type-specific field format and so the definition has to happen with the type argument.

Use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

to turn only titles of `@article` entries into italics and leave everything else as is.

Use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

to remove all type-specific formatting and make *all* titles into italics.

See the already linked [Remove Quotation Marks from Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864) for more extensive examples and explanations.