# How to make the title become italic for citing a book chapter in an edited book

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, citing

I am using the MWE from [Move names of editors followed by (Ed./Eds.) and a comma before title in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173638/move-names-of-editors-followed-by-ed-eds-and-a-comma-before-title-in-biblate)where I need to cite a book chapter in an edited book.

Basically from

```
Author A (1998) Title Chapter
```

to

Author A (1998) *Title Chapter*

[image]

to

[image]

Below is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
% \usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, maxnames = 99]{biblatex}

\usepackage[backend=biber, 
% style=authoryear, 
 style=authoryear-comp,
% citestyle=authoryear, 
dashed=false,
maxcitenames=2,
maxbibnames=99,
giveninits,
uniquename=init]{biblatex}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

% \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
% \renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\space}
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\space}

% \DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{english}{%
   \let\finalandcomma\empty
   \let\finalandsemicolon\empty
 }



% \DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection, unpublished]{title}{#1}
% \renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\ifentrytype{article}{\addcolon}{\addperiod\addspace}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{editorin}{given-family}

\newbibmacro*{byeditor:in}{%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\printnames[editorin]{editor}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{editorstrg}%
     \clearname{editor}}}

\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor}}
  {}{}

\xpatchbibdriver{inproceedings}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{in:}%
   \usebibmacro{byeditor:in}%
   \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
   \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
   \newunit\newblock
   \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {}{}



\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{lennon1965,
  author    = {John Lennon},
  booktitle = {A book with articles},
  editor    = {Paul McCartney and John Lennon and George Harrison and Richard Starkey},
  title     = {This is my article in this book},
  year      = {1965},
  location  = {Liverpool},
  pages     = {65--87},
  publisher = {Cavern Club},
}
@incollection{deborah123,
  author      = "Deborah Lewis and Marie O'Boyle-Duggan and Susan Poultney",
  title       = "Communication skills education and training in pre-registeration BSc Nursing",
  editor      = "David W. Kissane and Barry D. Bultz and Phyllis N. Butow and Carma L. Bylund and Simon Noble and Susie Wilkinson",
  booktitle   = "Oxford Textbook of Communication in Oncology and Palliative Care",
  publisher   = "Oxford University Press",
  address     = "Oxford",
  year        = 2017,
  pages       = "149-154",
  Edition = "2nd edn"
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
book done \parencite{deborah123}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/477326/35864 and keep in mind that `\mkbibemph` (which is used as `\mkbibemph{#1}` in field formats) gives you italics.

Comment: Specifically `\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}` will help with `@incollection`, but if you want something similar for `@article` and `@inbook` as well, something like `\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}` might be more useful.

Comment: @moewe. Thanks. It work well. What happened if I want my citing only a thesis which i am using `@phdthesis{phdthesisciting,
  title={phd ttitle},
  author={Hermann, Thomas},
  year={2002},
  }`. But the `phdthesis` is not define. I used `\DeclareFieldFormat[phdthesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}` to make the phdthesis citing title italic. But not working.

Comment: Internally, the type is called `thesis`. `@phdthesis` is supported for backwards compatibility and is remapped to `@thesis`. `\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}` should work. See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/862

Comment: @moewe, it works. Thanks, brillant!