# classicthesis bib style, quotation marks

Tags: biblatex, classicthesis

I am writing my thesis using the classic thesis style. The source can be found here https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis

The references appear with some funny quotes e.g

> Author. „Title of paper“ Conference. Date... etc

I want to get rid of the quotes around the title of paper. What in the source file do I need to change to make this happen?

I want it to read

> Author. Title of paper. Conference. Year... etc

The corresponding entry in my `bib.bib` file would look as follows.

```
@article{####,
author =   {Author},
title =    {Title of paper},
year =     2019,
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. You need to give us more information in order for us to be able to help you. Can you make a minimal compilable document that shows the problem. In particular, we need to see how you are actually producing the bibliography. As far as I know `classicthesis` does not determine anything related to bibliographies.

Comment: Does your main tex document contain a `\bibliographystyle` instruction?

Comment: Not as far as I can tell, I have used the basic template given in the link above. I just have no idea where this sort of thing is usually located. Do you have any insight as to where I would find the part to make the change. If I know that then I think I will be able to work it out. Thanks

Comment: Chances are the funny quotes are the typographically 'correct' (or at least commonly accepted as correct and commonly used) quotation marks of your document language (the ones you posted would for example be the correct German quotation marks). https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864 describes how you can get rid of them.

Comment: Looking at the zipped package in the link, there is a file called `classicthesis-config.tex` which is controlling this stuff. As @moewe suggests, this is because the file is loading `babel` with the `[ngerman]` option, which will give you this sort of quotes.  I suspect there will be more issues with this file, so I would learn some basic things about LaTeX first. See [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/11) and [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509)

Comment: Did https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864 help? If not, what did you try and how did it not work for you?

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864. If the answer there doesn't help you, please update your question with details about what you tried and how it didn't work for you and we can reopen it