# Biblatex-chicago omit prefix in postnote

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I am writing  my thesis in law using `biblatex-chicago`. We are writing in Danish and when citing articles, books etc. we are using the `postnote` to indicate the specific page, section etc.

When citing `@books` using `\autocite`, the reference in the footnote has no prefix in the `postnote`, but when citing `@jurisdiction`, `@legislation` and `@legal` it prints "at" as the prefix in the `postnote`.

I have tried using `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}` and `\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}` but it does not seem to work.

How do I omit prefixes in the `postnote` of these entry types?

Comment: Please accept the answer (if it suits for you) by clicking the tick mark

Answer (score 2):

`biblatex-chicago` is an extremely complicated style bundle, because it tries to implement the requirements of the Chicago Manual of Style as closely as possible with `biblatex`. As such it can be fairly difficult to modify `biblatex-chicago` to deviate from CMoS requirements. Some changes need lots of code, others have the potential to break desired behaviour in unexpected places.

As such I cannot guarantee that the following code does not have unintended side-effects; doubly so because there is no example document (MWE: [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)) in the question.

```
\renewrobustcmd*{\mkjuridprefix}[1]{#1}%
```

---

Your `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}` did not work, because `biblatex-chicago` uses type-specific formats to typeset the `postnote` field, but `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}` only changes the non-type-specific format. You could have used the starred version `\DeclareFieldFormat*{postnote}`

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{postnote}{% Changed for page compression option
  \ifboolexpr{%
    togl {cms@comprange}%
    and
    test {\ifpages{#1}}%
  }%
  {\iffieldundef{pagination}%
    {\mkcomprange{#1}}%
    {\mkcomprange[{\mkpageprefix[pagination]}]{#1}}}%
  {\iffieldundef{pagination}%
    {#1}%
    {\mkpageprefix[pagination]{#1}}}}%
```

to get rid of all type-specific formats first. (For more examples on type-specific format, see [Remove Quotation Marks from Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864.))

Comment: Thank you very much - it worked. I am new to overleaf and coding in general :)

Comment: @MarieAdserballeKristensen If the answer helped you solve your problem, please consider accepting the answer to show that the question is resolved. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.