# BibLaTeX: Different format style for author and editor

Tags: biblatex

I want to customize my bibliography and format the names in italics. But I do not want to format the editor's name in italics.

To format the names, I use the code below. But how can I differ the author's and editor's names?

How can I change the title to normalfont?

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
    @book{Test.2021,
        author   = {Mustermann, Thomas},
        year     = {2021},
        title    = {Mustertitel},
        editor   =  {Musterfrau, Erika},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-ibid, bibstyle=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\begin{document}
Dies ist ein Test.\footcite{Test.2021}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the name wrapper format to switch the name formatting more locally. In particular `sortname` applies only to the primary name in the bibliography and `labelname` to the citations.

Instead of `\mkbibnamefamily` and `\mkbibnamegiven` we redefine `\mkbibcompletename` to format the whole name at once.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-ibid, bibstyle=authortitle]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}{\mkbibemph}%
  #1}

\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{labelname}{sortname}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Test.2021,
  author = {Mustermann, Thomas},
  year   = {2021},
  title  = {Mustertitel},
  editor = {Musterfrau, Erika},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Dies ist ein Test.\footcite{Test.2021}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Mustermann, Thomas. Mustertitel. Ed. by Erika Musterfrau. 2021.]

---

I missed the line about the title formatting. Have a look at [Remove Quotation Marks from Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864) for help with that. If that doesn't help, I suggest you ask a new question since the title formatting is not directly connected to name formatting.