# Changing formatting in bibliography (bibLaTeX)

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the authoryear style with biber backend for biblatex.

I need the following formatting for my bibliography:

- I want @book titles to be in italic.
- I want @article titles, @thesis titles and @misc titles to be printed in regular font *without* quotation marks.

Right now, book titles are printed as I want them in italic. However:

- @misc titles are printed in italic
- @article and @thesis titles are printed in regular font, but with quotation marks.

How do I remove the quotation marks, and how do I get the @misc titles to be italic?

Comment: This question seems to be very similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595930/35864. If this is just an accidental double post, you may want to delete on of the two questions to avoid confusion. If there is a substantial difference between the two questions, it would be great if you could highlight it more.

Comment: Just in case the other question gets deleted, here is a copy of the comment I left over there. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864 might be able to help you. If that does not help you, please show us what you tried and how it did not work for you in a short example document (along with example `.bib` entries if requires), an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to rephrase the question you are wondering how to do to change a document like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
I refer to a book \autocite{nussbaum},
an article \autocite{moore},
a thesis \autocite{loh},
but no misc.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

so that it doesn't put quotation marks around the titles of the book and the thesis. (You also explicitly mention miscs, but as far as I understand they are already as you want them to be.)

Answer: Put these two lines in the preamble:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{#1}
```

Then you get this:

[image]

Comment: (The reason I didn't include a `@misc` is simply that there is no `@misc` in biblatex-examples.bib.)

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It helped.