# How to make formatting of bibliography with biblatex consistent

Tags: biblatex

I've been scouring the internet for the last hour trying to solve this and I can't yet. I have a list of references, a mix of books, articles/papers, and tech reports. Using `biblatex` means these are inconsistently formatted - some years are in brackets, other not, some titles are italicised, others not, and so on...

Here's my preamble code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none, maxbibnames=99, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begindocument
\printbibliography
\enddocument
```

My bibliography is really long, so I won't print all of it, but just as an example of a paper:

> Matthew  W.  Christensen,  William  K.  Jones,  and  Philip  Stier.  “Aerosols  enhance  cloud lifetime  and  brightness  along  the  stratus-to-cumulus  transition”.  In: *Proceedings  of  the National  Academy  of  Sciences* 117 (2020). visited on 19/04/2021.doi:10.1073/pnas.1921231117

with the `.bib` entry:

```
@article{christensen_aerosols_2020,
    title = {Aerosols enhance cloud lifetime and brightness along the stratus-to-cumulus transition},
    volume = {117},
    journal = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
    author = {Christensen, Matthew W. and Jones, William K. and Stier, Philip},
    year = {2020},
doi={10.1073/pnas.1921231117},
    note={visited on 19/04/2021}
```

and an example of a book:

> Esam  M.A.  Hussein. *Computed  Radiation  Imaging;  chapter  1  -  Radiation  Imaging.*  1st edition.  visited  on  09/07/2021.  Elsevier,  2011.doi:10.1016/B978-0-12-387777-2.00021-5

with `.bib` entry:

```
@book{hussein_inverse_2011,
title={Computed Radiation Imaging; chapter 1 - Radiation Imaging},
year={2011},
edition={1st edition},
publisher={Elsevier},
author={Esam M.A. Hussein},
doi={10.1016/B978-0-12-387777-2.00021-5},
note={visited on 09/07/2021},
}
```

How do I get one to look like the other?

- I don't care which - but either the paper title has to be in italics, without quotation marks, or the book needs to be in normal font, with quotation marks.
- The year either consistently in or consistently out of brackets.

I've tried a bunch of packages, but none of them really seem to work. I've also considered just calling them all the same entry type, but this doesn't work because obviously a book and an article have different kinds of associated information (publisher vs journal, for example..).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate the edit on the post! But the formatting was actually important - its not code, its to show how the result of code is, with italics/etc..which is why i didnt put it in the code quotation block

Comment: @Learn4life always feel free to rollback edits, if you click on the "edited 1 min ago" link there is an option to do that.  While you are there you could add a 2-entry `.bib` file so that people could get your result and test any answers.

Comment: Off-topic: Why do you show date-last-visited information for entries of type `@article` and `@book`? It's not as if the contents of a book or of an article published in a scholarly journal are going to change from one month to another, let alone from one year to another, right? The only entry types for which it may make sense to show a last-visited field are `@online`, `@misc`, `@unpublished`, and `@techreport` (and maybe a few others) whose contents could conceivably change meaningfully over time.

Comment: This convention is normal: when you're in a library, and you want to  read a book, you find the book by its title, whereas if you xant to read an article,  you have find the journal.

Comment: This is fair, but my supervisor asked me to make it consistent..so i have to make it consistent

Comment: @Learn4life - It may be time to remind your supervisor of what Ralph Waldo Emerson (1803-1882) had to say about (foolish) consistency: "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds, adored by little statesmen and philosophers and divines." For sure, your supervisor's opinion on the topic at hand is *simply dead wrong*, especially as the opinion flies in the face of well-established and well-tested bibliographic formatting practice. You'd be doing future students of his (hers?) a huge favor by making the case that it's time to drop the consistency pretense.

Answer (score 1):

The output of the standard styles is consistent and makes sense if you cast your mind back to the days of physical libraries and keep in mind that you could see book titles and journal titles on the spines (and the covers) of books/journal volumes and article titles and chapter titles only once you actually opened the book/volume. Titles that are typeset in italics can be seen in a library without opening books, titles in quotation marks can be found in the table of contents once the book is open.

<sub>This is not something that `biblatex` made up, it can be found in well-known and common styles like APA (https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/journal-article-references, https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/book-references), Chicago style (https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide/citation-guide-1.html), MLA (https://style.mla.org/works-cited/works-cited-a-quick-guide/), IEEE (https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE-Reference-Guide.pdf), New Hart's Rules.</sub>

It kind of makes sense to put the year for `@article`s in brackets because the volume and number information usually implies the year and is more fine grained.

<sub>Here different styles guides have different opinions. Chicago style puts `@article` years in parentheses, but not years of other types (https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide/citation-guide-1.html), IEEE style has no brackets for any year, Hart's has brackets for all years.</sub>

---

If you have to make the output more consistent *across types*

- [Remove Quotation Marks from Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864) explains how type-specific formatting works. For all-italic titles you could try

  ```
  \DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
  \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot}}
  \DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
  \DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
  \DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
  ```
- the parentheses around the date for `@article`s can easily be removed with `biblatex-ext` (full disclosure: I'm the author)

  ```
  \renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}
  \DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}
  ```

Note that if you want to cite only one chapter from a `@book` you should use the `@inbook` type and not the `@book` type with chapter number in the `title`. The MWE below contains entries for both Hussein's `@book` and `@inbook`. Indeed, using `@inbook` here makes things more consistent with `@article`s with the default settings, because they work analogous in the 'physical library' sense explained above. That said, usually I see full books listed in the bibliography and not individual chapters. (This is different when we are talking about `@incollection`s, i.e. papers in a collection volume. There `@incollection` is more common than `@collection`.)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-numeric, sorting=none, maxbibnames=99,]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibemph{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{christensen_aerosols_2020,
  title   = {Aerosols Enhance Cloud Lifetime and Brightness
             Along the Stratus-to-Cumulus Transition},
  volume  = {117},
  journal = {Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences},
  author  = {Christensen, Matthew W. and Jones, William K. and Stier, Philip},
  year    = {2020},
  doi     = {10.1073/pnas.1921231117},
  urldate = {2021-04-19},
}
@inbook{hussein_inverse_2011:chap1,
  author    = {Esam M. A. Hussein},
  title     = {Radiation Imaging},
  chapter   = {1},
  pages     = {1-12},
  booktitle = {Computed Radiation Imaging},
  year      = {2011},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Elsevier},
  doi       = {10.1016/B978-0-12-387777-2.00001-X},
  urldate   = {2021-07-09},
}
@book{hussein_inverse_2011:book,
  author    = {Esam M. A. Hussein},
  title     = {Computed Radiation Imaging},
  year      = {2011},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Elsevier},
  doi       = {10.1016/C2011-0-00133-3},
  urldate   = {2021-07-09},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,christensen_aerosols_2020,
  hussein_inverse_2011:chap1,worman,nussbaum,hussein_inverse_2011:book}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, 1998, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Comment: +1 for "if you want to cite only one chapter from a `@book` you should use the `@inbook` type". :-)

Comment: Using `@inbook` will make things consistent: "article title" in *Journal Title*, and "Chapter title" in *Book Title* (**not**: *Book Title, Chapter title*).

Comment: @Cicada Yeah, because `@article` and `@inbook` are analogous in that regard. But I assume the OP still wants to cite full books, so they still need some code to address that if they want all titles formatted alike.

Comment: @moewe, wow - thank you! The all italics thing worked beautifully. The removing brackets from date is giving me an error though, with the \volnumdatedelim (error: \volnumdatedelim undefined) - is there a package i need to use to make this work?

Comment: @Learn4life You will need the `biblatex-ext` bundle, which is available in MikTeX and TeX live (and has been since 2018). If `biblatex-ext` cannot be found there should be an error telling you that. Check the error messages in your document. How did you install your TeX system? (The TeX live that comes to linux distributions via `apt` is often woefully outdated.)