# Inconsistent brackets in references generated by biblatex

Tags: biblatex

Using the following commands

```
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, seconds=true, date=iso, urldate=iso, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
...

    \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

seems to result in inconsistent brackets around the publishing date. The first reference has no brackets, the next three do, and the fifth does not again. Can someone explain this to me? The journal does not have citation requirements other than "that they are consistent", so if this is consistent in some sense, it is fine I guess.

[image]

Comment: the output depends on the fields used in the bib entries about which you  have given no information

Comment: These are different types of citations: 1 is a book, 2-4 are journal articles, 5 is a chapter in an edited volume. Any citation style provides different requirements for these different types.

Comment: @musarithmia ahhh I did not know that - thank you! Yeah the difference seems to be `@article` vs `@book` and `@proceeding`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you see is consistent in way: The publication year of `@article`s is in parentheses, that of other types is not.

As for why that is the case we can only speculate. The year information is usually implied by `volume` and `number` of an `@article`, so it kind of makes sense to place the year after those in parentheses. (Incidentally the usual German translation of `volume` in this context is *Jahrgang*, which already contains the reference to "year".) This is not something that is found only in `biblatex`'s standard styles (though it is a bit less common than other design choices): The Chicago Manual of Style requires a similar behaviour (https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide/citation-guide-1.html).

If you want to get rid of the parentheses, a simple way is `biblatex-ext`'s `issuedate` field format. You'll just have to switch from `style=numeric,` to `style=numeric-ext,`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-numeric]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Emma Sigfridsson and Ulf Ryde. ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, 1998, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/605235/35864