# Locate configuration for alphabetic style

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am using an unofficial LaTeX template (officially there is only Word :() with biber, biblatex and alphabetic style. However, alphabetic is not completely correct. As an example, the font should be identical throughout the reference and not italic for some parts. Therefore I would like to make some adaptions and would like to check the configuration of the alphabetic style as some of my changes are not working. Could someone give me a hint where I can locate the definition?

To give you some ideas what I am talking about:

Example 1:

`\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{#1}` works (title normal, not italic; also works for booktitle of inproceedings),
`\DeclareFieldFormat[techreport]{title}{#1}` does not work (titel still italic; same for journal of article).

Example 2:

```
\ifentrytype{book}{
    \clearfield{url}                                   
    \clearfield{urldate}
}{}
\ifentrytype{article}{
    \clearfield{url}                               
    \clearfield{urldate}
}{}
}
```

removes the url both from articles and books (when citation data is taken from a website), but there is still an output for when it was accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most relevant definitions for (standard) `biblatex` styles live in

- [`biblatex.def`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def) - basic definitions for bibmacros and field formats
- [`standard.bbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/dev/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx) - drivers and higher-level bibmacros for all standard styles
- `<style>.bbx` ([`alphabetic.bbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/dev/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/alphabetic.bbx)) - bibliography-specific changes of `<style>`
- `<style>.cbx` ([`alphabetic.cbx`](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/dev/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/alphabetic.cbx)) - citation-specific changes of `<style>`

The `.bbx` and `.cbx` files may refer to other `.bbx` and `.cbx` files in some styles, so you may have to chase a few files.

You can find the location of these files on your machine by typing

```
kpsewhich <filename>
```

in the command line

---

For your first issue have a look at [Remove Quotation Marks from Style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864). Presumably

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
```

could help you as you want to override all type-specific formatting. (`\DeclareFieldFormat[techreport]{title}{#1}` does not work as expected, because `@techreport` it is just a convenience alias for what is internally called `@report`.)

---

For your second issue the problem is that internally there is no field called `urldate`. `urldate` is parsed into its date components. So you would have to delete `urlyear`. Personally, I find these cascading `\ifentrytype` definitions every inelegant and they can introduce lots of unwanted space if you do not protect the line ends properly ([What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864)). A nicer solution is to get rid of stuff via a sourcemap

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \pertype{book}
      \step[fieldset=url, null]
      \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
    }
  }
}
```

or presumably more something like

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pernottype{online}
      \step[fieldset=url, null]
      \step[fieldset=urldate, null]
    }
  }
}
```

This gets rid of the fields as early as possible.

Alternatively you can use that the `url` option can be set per-type.

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{url=false}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[online]{url=true}
```

(though the latter is the default anyway, so need not be made explicit).

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! Found the files, but did not dig through them yet as you already solved the most pressing issues.
`\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}` and `\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}` fixed all entries in the bibliography. And adding your last suggestion fixed the URL issue.