# How to set uppercase title of bib-items with BibLaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, titles, format

I am trying to set titles in bibliography and citations in upper case format (and I will be satisfied also for a solution only referred to bibliography).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\addbibresource{cited.bib}

\title{Just a joke}
\author{Francesco Contini}
\date{April 2023}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
We can argue that Milan is a bad city \cite[27--59]{contini2012}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

But, it doesn’t work.

This is my my cited.bib file:

```
@book{contini2012, author={Contini, Francesco},title={Milano e le vanità},subtitle={Misteri e scheletri della città della moda},publisher={Viva Roma Editore},address={Roma},year={2012}}
```

Of course I’d like subtitles to observe the same rules as titles.

Comment: The code you show suggests it wants to change the format of the `publisher`, not the title. Which do you want to change? Note also that the style the MWE uses is the `numeric` style, which mentions neither titles nor publishers in citations. I think it would help if you could add the example entry `contini2012` to your question and use it as an example to explain exactly which output you want.

Comment: @moewe Just edited the question. I apologize and I confirm that the question concerns title format. I asked also for cite command, because I am interested for a generic solution, not only for numeric style, but also for other bibstyle, like philosophy-classic or verbose etc. The example of the quote is a simple book item: @book{contini2012, author={Contini, Francesco},title={Milano e le vanità},subtitle={Misteri e scheletri della città della moda},publisher={Viva Roma Editore},address={Roma},year={2012}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to change the casing of the title, you redefine the special `titlecase` field format.

Casing commands are special and usually very sensitive with respect to the input they are fed, so they do not always work in all situations. In this case they don't work as expected when used for the `title` field format.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{contini2012,
  author    = {Contini, Francesco},
  title     = {Milano e le vanità},
  subtitle  = {Misteri e scheletri della città della moda},
  publisher = {Viva Roma Editore},
  address   = {Roma},
  year      = {2012},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
We can argue that Milan is a bad city \cite[27--59]{contini2012}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Francesco Contini. MILANO E LE VANITÀ. MISTERI E SCHELETRI DELLA CITTÀ DELLA MODA. Roma: Viva Roma Editore, 2012.]

Comment: Thanks! How can I remove the emphasis? Is there another option, or have I just to input your solution with \em command and neutralise the italic? \DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeUppercase{\em#1}}

Comment: @cicciocontini The emphasis comes from the "normal" `title` field format. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/462133/35864 for details on how to change that.

Comment: Well. So, I can use both commands. Thank you very much!